# How can I solve my foreign key constraint error when I know I created the relationships right?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, forward-engineer

```html
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema BrendasDMS
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `BrendasDMS` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema BrendasDMS
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `BrendasDMS` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
SHOW WARNINGS;
USE `BrendasDMS` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customers` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Customers` (
  `Customer_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ` FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Phone` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Customer_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `CustomerID_UNIQUE` (`Customer_ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Employees`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Employees` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Employees` (
  `Employee_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `City` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `State` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Zip` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `County` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `BirthDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `SSN` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Employee_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `FirstName_UNIQUE` (`FirstName` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Shops`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Shops` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Shops` (
  `Shop_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `County` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Zip` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Phone Number` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Shop_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`Shop_ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Sales`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Sales` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sales` (
  `Sale_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SaleDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Employee_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Customer_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Shop_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  `Price` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  `UnitOfMeasure` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sale_ID`, `Customer_ID`, `Employee_ID`, `Shop_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_Sale_Employee1_idx` (`Employee_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Sale_Customer1_idx` (`Customer_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Sale_Shops1_idx` (`Shop_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Sale_Employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Employee_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Employees` (`Employee_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Sale_Customer1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Customer_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Customers` (`Customer_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Sale_Shops1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Shop_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Shops` (`Shop_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Products`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Products` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Products` (
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProductName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `UnitOfMeasure` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Price` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `RecipeID_UNIQUE` (`Product_ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `SaleLineItems`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `SaleLineItems` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SaleLineItems` (
  `Sale_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Sale_ID`, `Product_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_Sale_has_Product_Sale1_idx` (`Sale_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_SaleLineItem_Product1_idx` (`Product_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Sale_has_Product_Sale1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Sale_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Sales` (`Sale_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_SaleLineItem_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Products` (`Product_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Vendors`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Vendors` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Vendors` (
  `Vendor_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `VendorType` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Address` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Zip` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Vendor_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`Vendor_ID` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Orders`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Orders` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Orders` (
  `Order_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Vendor_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  `UnitOfMeasure` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Price` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_ID`, `Vendor_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID_UNIQUE` (`Order_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Orders_Vendor1_idx` (`Vendor_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_Vendor1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Vendor_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Vendors` (`Vendor_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `EmployeeShop`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `EmployeeShop` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EmployeeShop` (
  `Shop_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Employee_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Shop_ID`, `Employee_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_Shop_has_Employee_Employee1_idx` (`Employee_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Shop_has_Employee_Shop1_idx` (`Shop_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Shop_has_Employee_Shop1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Shop_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Shops` (`Shop_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Shop_has_Employee_Employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Employee_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Employees` (`Employee_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Ingredients`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Ingredients` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ingredients` (
  `Ingredient_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `IngredientName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `UnitOfMeasure` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  `Price` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ingredient_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `OrderLineItems`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `OrderLineItems` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `OrderLineItems` (
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  `Order_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Ingredient_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Order_ID`, `Ingredient_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_OrderLineItems_Orders1_idx` (`Order_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_OrderLineItems_Ingredients1_idx` (`Ingredient_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_OrderLineItems_Orders1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Order_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Orders` (`Order_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_OrderLineItems_Ingredients1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Ingredient_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Ingredients` (`Ingredient_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = ndbcluster;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Recipes`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Recipes` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Recipes` (
  `Recipe_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Directions` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Recipe_ID`, `Product_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Recipe_ID_UNIQUE` (`Recipe_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Recipes_Products1_idx` (`Product_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Recipes_Products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Products` (`Product_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RecipeIngredients`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `RecipeIngredients` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RecipeIngredients` (
  `Quantity` INT NOT NULL,
  `Ingredient_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `UnitOfMeasure` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Price` DECIMAL NOT NULL,
  `Recipe_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Ingredient_ID`, `Recipe_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_RecipeIngredients_Ingredients2_idx` (`Ingredient_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_RecipeIngredients_Recipes1_idx` (`Recipe_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_RecipeIngredients_Ingredients2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Ingredient_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Ingredients` (`Ingredient_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_RecipeIngredients_Recipes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Recipe_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Recipes` (`Recipe_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I have created a lot of tables and I am now trying to forward engineer my logical model into a physical database, but I am having trouble when it keeps saying "Can't add a foreign key constraint".

However, I know that the error is related to the Products referencing the Recipe_ID, but when I click on the relationship line from Recipes table to RecipeIngredients table, I see that the FK Recipe_ID **IS REFERENCING** the Recipe_ID primary key column in the Recipes table, not the Product table.

[image: SQL Model]

If that is the case, why is problem occurring? Any suggestions except recreating all of the tables again. Here is my picture model and picture of my problem.

[image: Forward Engineer]

Comment: Please, do not edit the answer this way. Or at the very least specify that your question has changed. Otherwise, people reading the question and an answer *to a previous question* will find nothing useful, or even believe the answerer was hallucinating :-)

Comment: @ LSerni What are you talking about?

Comment: @ LSerni What happened to your suggestions?

Comment: Your first script contained a schema, and now the question contains another (which, on my MySQL 5.6.35, works -- once I remove the `SQL_MODE` setting). I feel that my previous answer is no longer relevant.

Comment: @LSemi - It's not forward engineering. It has an error which says (Error 1286)"Unknown storage engine 'ndbcluster' " for the OrderLineItems table. I know there are different search engines for different tables, but I don't know how to get this table back to search engine of InnoDB.

Comment: My suggestion would be to manually edit the script and replace `ndbcluster` with `innodb` , then just feed it to MySQL from the command line or through SQLyog or HeidiSQL. That's what I would do; I am not familiar with MySQL Workbench [ which is a pity, seeing the nice diagrams - I usually do them by hand in yEd ], and I haven't read its manual either.

Comment: @Lsemi- Why do people create tables by hand anyway? Technology is powerful these days!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Lsemi- Thanks that worked!!!!!!!